# How can I get dynamic content from a .txt file to display in multiple html pages when they are loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a text file: 'm_data.txt' on the server that has a running total 77 (for example) in it. The total is updated by a push.php page that writes to the .txt file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 13.1" />
</head>
<body>




<form action="" method="get">

  <label for="number">RunningTotal:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="number" name="number" value="0"><br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
  <!-- <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="sendform();"/> -->
  
</form>


<?php if (isset($_GET["number"])) { ?>


<p> Picked Up <?php echo $_GET["number"]; ?>.</p>

<?php
$myfile = fopen("m_data.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $_GET['number']; 
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>

<?php } ?>


</body>





</html>
```

I want to display that total constantly within 2 pages box1.html and box2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Box 1</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="autoM_Update.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<style>
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: 250px;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="liveDataM" class="relative" class="anim" class="my_textBold">?</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Box 2</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="autoM_Update.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<style>
div.relative2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  height: 175px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: 175px;
  margin: auto;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="liveDataM" class="relative2" class="anim" class="my_textBold">?</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

if the total is changed in the txt file it should update instantly in the pages on the screen, without requiring to hit the page refresh button. This is done thru the 'autoM_Update.js' file also on the server.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function()
{
    var xhr = null;

    getXmlHttpRequestObject = function()
    {
        if(!xhr)
        {               
            // Create a new XMLHttpRequest object 
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        return xhr;
    };

    updateLiveData = function()
    {
        var now = new Date();
        // Date string is appended as a query with live data 
        // for not to use the cached version 
        var url = 'm_data.txt?' + now.getTime();
        xhr = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = evenHandler;
        // asynchronous requests
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        // Send the request over the network
        xhr.send(null);
    };

    updateLiveData();

    function evenHandler()
    {
        // Check response is ready or not
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
        {
            dataDiv = document.getElementById('liveDataM');
            // Set current data text
            dataDiv.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            // Update the live data every 1 sec
            setTimeout(updateLiveData(), 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

This works fine when pages box1 and box2 are displayed by themselves.The refresh button does not need to be pressed. Whenever I edit the push.php page the number automatically updates.

But the issue is, that I want the 2 pages box1 and box2, to appear only when loaded inside append2.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Append2</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="autoM_Update.js"></script>
    

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>



body { 

}

table, th {
  table-layout: absolute;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  width: 900px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div1 {
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 900px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

div.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  height: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 250px;
  margin: auto;
}

div.relative2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  height: 175px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 175px;
  margin: auto;
}

</style>



</head>
<body>


<div ><button class="button1" onclick="getContent1();">Load Box1</button></div>
<br>
<div ><button class="button1" onclick="getContent2();">Load Box2</button></div>


<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="div1" align="center">This is Today's Date</div>
<div class="relative" id="content1"></div>
<div class="relative2" id="content2"></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>

</body>

<script>


function getContent1() {
    $('#content1').load("box1.html");
}

function getContent2() {
    $('#content2').load("box2.html");
}


</script>

</html>
```

When the boxes are loaded dynamically the number no longer appears or is updated. And even just clicking the refresh button to get the number to show is not a solution for me. I need the number to update automatically whenever the .txt file is changed. How can I get the .txt file changes to propagate down the chain to box1 and box2 if it is loaded within the append2.html file. Any help, insight and code provided examples that you can give me will be really appreciated.

Also this is using getXmlHttpRequestObject in the .js file. Chrome is giving a message that... Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. What are alternative solutions to solve this issue if this may not work down the road. thanks Mark.

Comment: Chrome should not show that warning, as you've an asynchronous call (`xhr.open("GET", url, true);`). In practice, there's no alternatives on the client-side, but you can take a look at web-sockets, with web-sockets your server can contact a browser when needed.

Comment: I feel that AJAX is not the best option to accomplish the `instant` update of which you speak as it would require almost constant polling. You are not using `iframes` to load the two `boxes` in `append2.html` so you won't be able to correctly load a full HTML page into a DIV element. To achieve the instant update you really need `WebSockets` or possibly `Server Sent Events` would also be suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than endlessly polling using `XMLHttpRequest` - where each of the pages to be included is intended to fire requests every second to retrieve the same data one alternative you might wish to consider would be to use an `EventSource` connection in conjunction with `postMessage`

In the above code you hope to include the two `box` pages within a parent page ( `append2.html` ) - but to do so would be invalid as an HTML page can only have a single `HTML`,`HEAD` and `BODY` section so to include entire webpages inside DIV elements is not the way to proceed - instead the obvious choice would be to use `iframe` elements that load the other pages. In the demo below these iframes are statically loading the box1, box2 pages but you could load these dynamically.

To mimic your setup there are 5 pages involved:-

```
sse.php ~ the file that reads the textfile every N seconds and sends data back
push.php ~ form that allows user to update text file with new number
append2.html ~ two statically declared iframes, content populated using `postMessage`
box1.html, box2.html ~ identical pages that `listen` for messages from append2.html
```

**sse.php**

```
<?php
    set_time_limit( 0 );
    ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', 1);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
    ob_end_clean();
    

    $sleep=1;                   # send data every $sleep seconds
    $evt='txtupdate';           # Event name used in Javascript
    $file='m_data.txt';         # read this file for updated number
    
    #utility method to send formatted data
    function sse( $evtname='iss', $data=null, $retry=1000 ){
        if( !is_null( $data ) ){
            echo "event:".$evtname."\r\n";
            echo "retry:".$retry."\r\n";
            echo "data:" . json_encode( $data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );
            echo "\r\n\r\n";
        }
    }
    # headers... consider modifying `Allow-Origin` to increase security
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
    
    #infinite loop - read file and send data payload
    while( true ){
        if( connection_status() != CONNECTION_NORMAL or connection_aborted() ) break;
        
        $payload=[
            'count' =>  intval( file_get_contents( $file ) )
        ];
        call_user_func( 'sse', $evt, $payload );
        
        /* -- Send output -- */
        if( @ob_get_level() > 0 ) for( $i=0; $i < @ob_get_level(); $i++ ) @ob_flush();
        @flush();
        
        sleep( $sleep );
        $payload = null;
    }
    
    if( @ob_get_level() > 0 ) {
        for( $i=0; $i < @ob_get_level(); $i++ ) @ob_flush();
        @ob_end_clean();
    }
?>
```

**push.php**

```
<?php
    $file='m_data.txt';         # read & update this file ( same as referenced in SSE )
    $autoupdate=true;           # does the user need to manually update the number in the form?
    $int=file_exists( $file ) ? intval( file_get_contents( $file ) ) : 0;
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['action'] ) ){
        ob_clean();
        $json=[];
        
        if( $_POST['action'] == 'update-file' ){
            $number=intval( $_POST['number'] );
            if( $autoupdate ) $number++;
            
            file_put_contents( $file, $number );
            $json=json_encode( array( 'number'=>$number ) );
        }
        exit( $json );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>push</title>
        <script>
            /*
                send ajax request to server, update source textfile
                and return the new count. Use the callback to update
                the displayed number.
            */
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',(e)=>{
                let form=document.forms.push;
                let bttn=form.querySelector('[type="button"]');
                
                bttn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
                    
                    let fd=new FormData( form );
                        fd.append('action','update-file');
                        
                    fetch( location.href, { method:'post',body:fd } )
                        .then( r=>{ return r.json() })
                        .then( json=>{
                            form.number.value=json.number;
                        })                  
                });
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='push'>
            <label>Number: <input type='number' name='number' value='<?=$int;?>' /></label>
            <?php
                if( $autoupdate ){
                    echo "
                    <p>You do NOT need to manually update this number - simply click the button to increment the counter by 1</p>";
                }
            ?>
            <input type='button' value='Update' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**append2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Display</title>
        <style>
            iframe{
                width:30%;
                margin:1rem;
                border:5px dashed rgba(100,100,100,0.25);
                border-radius:1rem;
                background:whitesmoke;
                padding:0;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            let evtsource = new EventSource( 'sse.php', { withCredentials: false } );
                evtsource.addEventListener( 'txtupdate', function(e){
                    if( !e.origin == window.location.origin ) return false;
                    let json=JSON.parse( e.data );
                    
                    let b1=document.getElementById('b1').contentWindow;
                    let b2=document.getElementById('b2').contentWindow;
                    
                        b1.postMessage( json.count );
                        b2.postMessage( json.count );
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- box 1 -->
        <iframe id='b1' src='box1.html'></iframe>
        
        <!-- box 2 -->
        <iframe id='b2' src='box2.html'></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**box1 & box2**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>Box 1||Box 2</title>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener( 'message', (e)=>{
                if( e.origin == window.location.origin ){
                    document.getElementById('liveDataM').textContent=e.data;
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='liveDataM' class='relative anim my_textBold'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Open two browser tabs - load `push.php` in one and `append2.html` in the other and update the textfile to see the value reflected in both iframes simultaneously. Hope it helps/